# How to subset the all rows which are less than particular time in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have to subset the data frame rows which are less than particular time.

data:

```
time
2020-10-29 07:08:02
2020-10-29 07:10:00
2020-10-29 07:25:18
2020-10-29 07:28:15
2020-10-29 07:30:00
```

I have written code like below:

```
for i in range(0,(data).shape[0]):
   #i=0
   data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'])
   df = data.loc[data['time'] <= data['time'][i]]
```

If I want to subset for i =2, I should get output like below:

```
output:
time
2020-10-29 07:08:02
2020-10-29 07:10:00
2020-10-29 07:25:18
```

I am getting below error:

```
KeyError: 0
```

Please, tell me where I am gone wrong.

Comment: It would help to add some sample data, and a sample of your expected output.

Comment: @Chris, I have added the data and output. Please, help to me to get that output in python. I am new to python. I know how to do in R.

Comment: `data.loc[df['time']<=data.iloc[i]['time']]`

Comment: @Chris, Thank you so much it is working now. Can you please, explain the difference between two codes

Comment: I feel like it should work either way honestly.